# Noob question: Includes in Netbeans + MinGW

Tags: c++, netbeans, include, compiler-errors, mingw

I downloaded this C++ project:
http://lagrange.ime.usp.br/~lobato/packing/
I tried to run it on a Mac and it works wonderfully.
Now i need to run it on a Windows 7 machine with **Netbeans 7.0** and **MinGW Compiler 5.1.6**: it doesn't compile. I get errors on includes:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
```

I found out that MinGW doesn't have these headers... how can i solve this stupid problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first step would be to comment out those #includes and see what happens. If you get compile errors then you are going to have to look at the problematic code and figure out what to replace it with.

It's not the problem that's stupid it's the wonderful code you downloaded which seems to be platform specific for no obvious reason.

Comment: Nah its Windows for not supporting commonly used headers. It'll work on any posix-compliant system... In any case the solution would be to use cygwin.

Comment: My Unix system doesn't support <windows.h>. It's a commonly used header! But yes, cygwin is a good suggestion.